# Making a LED portal for DnD campaign

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, led, batteries, resistors

I am brand new to circuitry and general electronics, and wanted to try something new with my DnD terrain. I 3D print, and I'm designing a center piece portal for an upcoming campaign. I made the circuit in Tinkercad and wanted some input on if I wired things correctly.

I plan on using 2 AA batteries to power the 6 LEDs, but I read on a few other posts that doing a series like this would be dangerous. Tinkercad didn't highlight any issues with it so I wanted to double check with you all. I wanted to be on the safe side and do a parallel circuit, but I don't really understand how to without a breadboard. I also am unsure what kind of resistor I need for these leds, but I heard 100 ohms should be good enough for low voltage LEDs.

[image]

Comment: "but I read on a few other posts that doing a series like this would be dangerous."  It was some rubbish you read, LEDs don't behave nicely in parallel.  I suggest using six 1k resistors, one for each LED.

Comment: thank you for your comment! Just a few questions though, how do you know i need 1000 ohms for the resistors? I want to know how to figure something like that out! and how come you use a resistor for each LED?

Comment: 1k is a just a guess, it would give about 1 mA of current per LED which I guess is reasonably bright.  I should have said that you should experiment a little with te resistance value to find the brightness you like.

Comment: I don't understand why you think a series circuit would be dangerous. It would likely just not work. The parallel circuit is also problematic. If one LED has smaller voltage than others, it will be the brightest, and if the difference of LED voltages is large then only one may light up.

Comment: Almost nothing with 2xAA batteries is "dangerous". Rechargeable ones can severely overheat if short-circuited (not sure if they can catch fire), and all batteries can have corrosive chemicals if cut open, but apart from that, there's not a lot that can go wrong with 2 AA's.

Comment: At 100 kΩ TinkerCad would show nothing, because this circuit would just draw minuscule amount of current and do nothing else. And only "danger" is that it will have very uneven brightness and you'll end frustrated.

Comment: @OskarSkog really? I have those same cheap china leds, but i have pushed over 150ma through them. fsr they dont apear to get any brighter

Answer (score 8):

**1.** In your circuit, the resistor is 100 kΩ and not 100 Ω.

**2.** Connecting LEDs in parallel like in your diagram is a bad idea. It is necessary to provide each LED with a resistor.

To calculate resistor *R = (Battery Voltage – LED voltage) / LED current*

For example if you have 3 V battery and standard green LEDs (2.2 V, 10 mA) your resistors will be *R = (3 - 2.2) / 0.01 = 80 Ω*. You can use 100 Ω instead.

**3.** So, your schematic should looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmPOyi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: thank you for the diagram!! it's super helpful, and I recreated my circuit like you have there: https://i.imgur.com/TTHfE1U.png 

It's not the prettiest thing, but I think I was able to visualize it better with your diagram, only issue now is designing a housing to fit it all in, but its a start! Silly question, but would you have to heatshrink the "T-intersection" of the circuit? or just at the ends of the LEDS? thank you again!

Comment: I think it's best to do something like a garland. Those solder a resistor to each LED, strip the wires of the same length and solder 2 wires to each leg of the LED (from the previous one to the next) and put these wires together with the resistor and the leg of the LED into heatshrink
Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S08Rm.png

Comment: Lots of projects do successfully use LEDs in parallel with a shared resistor. I agree that separate resistors are *better* but apparently shared resistors can be *good enough*.

Comment: I'd add that you can buy LEDs with integrated resistors, to save time and effort. For example [this ones](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14563) (not affiliated) with 3-5V range and no effort required.

Answer (score 6):

It definitely won't be dangerous.

There are people who will tell you that wiring LEDs in parallel won't work. But if you look closely at any cheap battery powered LED Christmas (or Halloween) lights, that's exactly what they do. There is usually one resistor in the battery box.

But it only works if all the LEDs are identical. Same colour and ideally from the same batch.

If you mix LEDs of different colours, then the ones nearest the red end of the spectrum Will take all the current.

Comment: This is ill advice. Some products may work that way but in fact, its just bad engineering. Current will never be 100% equally distributed even if you use LEDs from the same batch. This always result in slightly more or less current between different LEDs. Of course its normally not an issue when an LED gets say 1mA more than initially calculated, but it probably would already be noticeably brighter than the other ones because of the non-linearity. The real problems start when 1 LED stops working. Now all other LEDs "receive" that extra current. This may even cause cascading failures.

Comment: Likely the festive LEDs are in fact *engineered* to work in parallel. LEDs are likely binned to have close enough match in LED voltages so they can be as simple and cheap as possible. So generally parallel LEDs won't work unless you put effort to make it work. Simply purchasing a few LEDs and putting them in parallel is not guaranteed to work as expected.

Comment: It will often work well enough. Whether it is "bad engineering" or "good engineering" to cheap out on simple decoration lights everyone can decide for themselves. And +1 for this answer on pointing out that the only real danger is that some LEDs will get more current than others.

Comment: @Rev commercial LED "Light Engines" which you'll find in everything from 2x4 "troffers" to street lighting routinely put multiple LEDs in parallel and then put those parallel sets in series to use 100's of LED in the same fixture (with no current limiting resistor at all since they're driven by a constant-current LED driver).

Comment: Some valid comments. "generally parallel LEDs won't work unless you put effort to make it work" probably nails it down. You can't say that its the worst idea per se, but you probably have to put some extra work in to make such a design reliable. I retract my down-vote, but the answer could've pointed out the potential issues better. The first two paragraphs are a bit misleading to start with.

Comment: My experience with LEDs in parallel is that they work for a while, but after a few months they get uneven.